# Maximum pseudo-likelihood estimator for soft-core point process

Tags: r, statistics, mle

I am trying to fit a [soft-core point process model](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatstat/versions/1.56-1/topics/Softcore) on a set of point pattern using maximum pseudo-likelihood. I followed the instructions given in this [paper](http://wildfire.stat.ucla.edu/pdflibrary/baddeleyturnerpseudo.pdf) by Baddeley and Turner

And here is the R-code I came up with

```
`library(deldir)
 library(tidyverse)
 library(fields)

 #MPLE

 # irregular parameter k

 k <- 0.4

 ## Generate dummy points 50X50. "RA" and "DE" are x and y coordinates


dum.x <- seq(ramin, ramax, length = 50)
dum.y <- seq(demin, demax, length = 50)
dum <- expand.grid(dum.x, dum.y)
colnames(dum) <- c("RA", "DE")

## Combine with data and specify which is data point and which is dummy, X is the point pattern to be fitted

bind.x <- bind_rows(X, dum) %>%
mutate(Ind = c(rep(1, nrow(X)), rep(0, nrow(dum))))

## Calculate Quadrature weights using Voronoi cell area

w <- deldir(bind.x$RA, bind.x$DE)$summary$dir.area

## Response
y <- bind.x$Ind/w

# the sum of distances between all pairs of points (the sufficient statistics)

tmp <- cbind(bind.x$RA, bind.x$DE)
t1 <- rdist(tmp)^(-2/k)
t1[t1 == Inf] <- 0
t1 <- rowSums(t1)
t <- -t1

# fit the model using quasipoisson regression

fit <- glm(y ~ t,  family = quasipoisson, weights = w)
`
```

However, the fitted parameter for `t` is negative which is obviously not a correct value for a softcore point process. Also, my point pattern is actually simulated from a softcore process so it does not make sense that the fitted parameter is negative. I tried my best to find any bugs in the code but I can't seem to find it. The only potential issue I see is that my sufficient statistics is extremely large (on the order of 10^14) which I fear may cause numerical issues. But the statistics are large because my observation window spans a very small unit and the average distance between a pair of points is around 0.006. So sufficient statistics based on this will certainly be very large and my intuition tells me that it should not cause a numerical problem and make the fitted parameter to be negative.

Can anybody help and check if my code is correct? Thanks very much!